# Multiset Matching

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, matching-theory, multisets

Suppose we have two multisets of positive integers, $A$ and $B$, where the sum of the elements (counted with multiplicity) of the two multisets is the same. Starting from $A$, we would like to arrive at $B$ by applying one of two rules in turn. On a turn, we may either:

1. Choose an element, $x$, of $A$ and two smaller integers $y$ and $z$ such that $x = y+z$. Decrease the multiplicity of $x$ by $1$ and increase the multiplicity of $y$ and $z$ by 1 each (increasing the relevant multiplicity by $2$ if $y=z$). There is no requirement for $y$ or $z$ to have been elements of $A$ prior to this. Applying this move incurs a one point penalty.

or

2. Choose two elements, $y$ and $z$, of $A$, reduce each of their multiplicities by $1$ (by $2$ if $y=z$ but we can only choose two equal elements if the multiplicity was at least $2$ to begin with) and increase the multiplicity of $y+z$ by $1$. This move can be used even if $y+z$ was not an element of $A$. Applying this move incurs no penalty.

The resulting multiset, $A'$, will then be our new "$A$" for the next turn and the sum of its elements (counted with multiplicity) will be the same as it was for $A$. We would like to use these rules to go from $A$ to $B$. For instance, suppose $A$ is $\left\{2, 5, 7\right\}$ and $B$ is $\left\{1, 2, 3, 3, 5\right\}$. We could use move 1 to go from $A$ to $\left\{1, 2, 5, 6\right\}$ and then use it again to go to $\left\{1, 2, 3, 3, 5\right\}$, incurring a total of two points.

**My Question**

What would be a computationally efficient algorithm for going from $A$ to $B$ while incurring the smallest possible number of points, i.e. using move $1$ as few times as possible? Is it possible to construct a much more efficient algorithm if we are happy to just be close to the minimum number of penalty points in some sense, perhaps even an informal sense of just having a "sensible" algorithm for keeping the number of points incurred small?

**My Thoughts so Far**

First of all, there's no benefit to applying moves of type $2$ until we have done all of our type $1$ moves. Secondly, if $A$ and $B$ share some elements, there will always be an optimal solution which just preserves them, i.e. at no point reduces their multiplicity in our "$A$" beyond their multiplicity in $B$.

If $A$ has $a$ elements counted with multiplicity and $B$ has $b$ elements counted with multiplicity, then we will need to incur at least $\max{\left(0, b-a\right)}$ penalty points because we will need to "create" at least that many new elements by using a type $1$ move. We will never need to incur more than $b-1$ points because we could always just use move $2$ to merge all of $A$'s elements together and then use move $1$ $b-1$ times to peel off the elements of $B$.

One way of thinking about the number of points incurred that might be helpful is to keep track of how many elements of $B$ each element of $A$ "contributes" to forming. For instance, if there is a $5$ in $A$ and we use rule $1$ to split it into a $2$, which is matched with a $2$ in $B$, and a $3$ which is combined with a $4$ from somewhere else using rule $2$ to form a $7$ that is matched with a different element of $B$, then we can say that the $5$ from $A$ contributed to two elements of $B$, the $2$ and the $7$. Every element of $B$ that a given element of $A$ contributes is another point incurred so we would like elements of $A$ to contribute to as few elements of $B$ as possible on average.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-hard, by reduction from the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Let $A$ be any multiset, whose sum (counting multiplicity) is $s$.  Let $B=\{s/2,s/2\}$ be the multiset containing two copies of $s/2$.  Then there exists a solution to transform $A$ to $B$ with no points (i.e., using only type-2 moves), iff $A$ is a "yes" instance for the partition problem.

You can also reduce from the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), if you find that conceptually simpler.

---

If you need to solve it in practice, you can formulate it as an instance of integer linear programming and solve it with an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  Let $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$.  Introduce integer variables $t_{i,j}$ and zero-or-one variables $s_{i,j}$, with the following intended meaning:

- Via type-1 moves, we split $a_i$ into the sum $a_i=t_{i,1}+\dots+t_{i,m}$ (ignore the 0 terms in this sum).
- Then, via type-2 moves, we construct $b_j$ as the sum $t_{1,j} + \dots+t_{n,j}$.
- Therefore, $t_{i,j}$ contains the contribution from $a_i$ that flows to $b_j$.
- If $s_{i,j}=0$, then $t_{i,j}=0$.
- Therefore, $s_{i,1}+\dots+s_{i,n}-1$ counts the number of type-1 moves applied to $a_i$.

Given these ideas, we can enforce them using integer linear inequalities, as follows:

- $a_i=t_{i,1}+\dots+t_{i,m}$, for each $i$
- $t_{1,j} + \dots+t_{n,j}=b_j$, for each $j$
- $t_{i,j} \ge 0$, for each $i,j$
- $t_{i,j} \le M \cdot s_{i,j}$, for each $i,j$, where $M=\min(a_i,b_j)$ is a constant that was chosen to be sufficiently large.

Finally, we minimize the sum $\sum_{i,j} s_{i,j} - m$, as that counts the number of type-1 moves needed.

Comment: Ah, so it's presumably not possible to solve it exactly in polynomial time. Do you have any thoughts on how you might construct a polynomial time algorithm that keeps the number of type-1 moves reasonably small?

Comment: @SpringLandMid, I don't, but many ILP solvers have a way to impose a time limit -- you can ask them to give you the best solution they've found within that time bound.  Maybe someone else will have a more clever solution.

Comment: You can take $M=\min(a_i,b_j)$.  That is, $t_{i,j} \le \min(a_i,b_j) s_{i,j}$.

Comment: @RobPratt, good point, thank you.  I've edited my answer accordingly.